# Graql insert query: duplicate Var objects

Tags: java, graph-databases, vaticle-typeql, mindmapsdb, vaticle-typedb

```
Var message = var().isa("message");
insert(message).execute();

Var relation = var().isa("connection")
    .rel("role1", id("existing-id"))
    .rel("role2", message);
insert(relation).execute();
```

Executing the following creates two instances of a message.

Is this expected? If it is, is it because I did not assign an ID, or because I have used two insert statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. You're correct at guessing that assigning an id will solve the issue:

```
Var message = var().id("my-message").isa("message");
```

The reason this happens is because a `Var` does not represent a single concept. Instead, it represents a pattern to match in the graph. In this instance, the `Var` only says "things that are messages", not any particular message.

You could also assign a variable name, e.g. `Var message = var("x"). ...`
For this to work, you would have to execute only a single `insert`.

Comment: But why does the `message` variable get inserted in the second statement? Aren't we just inserting the `relation` variable? And after the the first `message` was executed, should the `message` variable be updated to refer to the concept that has been inserted?

Comment: The insert query will insert all patterns passed to it, including any "nested" patterns, such as the `message` in `relation` above. `message` is just a query component, not a concrete object in the graph. It represents the notion of "a thing that is a message", not any particular message.